# how to communicate with web service

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

I am doing my final year project in SOA.  I need to communicate with the webservice via my java coding.  What is the best way to communicate with web service.  Please, refer me any way.  if possible post me the tutorial links, or youtube video links.  Please.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of webservices (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqsx.html), SOAP and REST. REST are easy. I am not sure if you already have a web service, if not then you will first need to create a webservice and then consume it.

If you already have a webservice that is provided by some third party then you need to ask them for the WSDL file. This WSDL will help you create client classes, that will let you communicate/consume the webservice hosted by third party.

There are few implementations of JAX-WS. Simpler one and most popular include: apache cxf (http://cxf.apache.org/), apache axis (https://axis.apache.org/axis/), spring web services (http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/), java webservices (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijti.html).

I would recommend you this link: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html and this book (Imbibing Java Web Services by Mudunuri, Srinivas) which I found easy to follow: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Imbibing-Java-Services-Srinivas-Mudunuri-ebook/dp/B008A00T4E/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1394550780&sr=1-6&keywords=java+web+services
Its upto you which ever framework you want to use, good luck for the project.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Syed for the wishes.  But, i have zero knowledge about what you said.  But, i already work with soap webservices on creating and consuming.  Now, i badly need to develop a program which will send request and receive response from webservice in a java program without any special tool...which means..creating a webservice in netbeans and then deploying it.after deploying, just close it, access via the java coding that is my requirement.